# Turn raw url into clickable links

Tags: custom-field, links

I have a custom field that contains a bunch of urls in it. I want them to be clickable links in that custom field only. How can I do this? I could just manually convert them to html links but that's too time consuming for 100+ links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `make_clickable()`:

```
$text = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_key', TRUE );
echo make_clickable( $text );
```

Comment: where do I place that code? do I replace my_key with the name of the custom field?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Where you want to print or store the result is up to you.